# Drools - error with “after” operator

Tags: drools

Recently, I has been working with Drools component.
 I found a very interesting thing.
 The problem is that drool engine do not fire conditions which use “after” operator.
 This condition does not always work. Error case requires that external events come to the system immediately.
 It’s mean that if to set timer for 10 milliseconds between coming events everything works fine.
 If events comes into the system continuously (without timer, see my code below) after some time rules not fire.

For more information please red my blog: http://i-liger.com/article/problem-drools

I will be very grateful for any help or suggestion.
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Instead of sending us to your blog, please post the relevant information in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The after evaluator correlates two events and matches when the temporal distance from the current event to the event being correlated belongs to the distance range declared for the operator.

The temporal distance interval for the after operator is optional: 
 If two values are defined (like in the example below), the interval starts on the first value and finishes on the second. 
 If only one value is defined, the interval starts on the value and finishes on the positive infinity. 
If no value is defined, it is assumed that the initial value is 1ms and the final value is the positive infinity.

solution: change "after" --> "after[0ms]"

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks that you are not doing things right.. I mean..looking at your rules you are checking if one event comes after the other, but drools will check all the possible combinations in all the rules that you wrote. Checking the status of your application adding those rules becomes not maintainable. Can you please specify exactly what are you trying to achieve with Events and Drools? we can help you to design your solution.
Cheers